# Clustering with proportional threshold

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I'm starting learning about clustering so perhaps this is a basic question. The idea is to generate clusters out of an array of floats, 1 dimension and N dimensions, get the mean value of each dimension of each cluster, and the array elements that get into a cluster should be within a range like this:

```
elem_val >= cluster_mean - (cluster_mean * threshold)
elem_val <= cluster_mean + (cluster_mean * threshold)
```

So the limits of the cluster are proportional to the mean value of the cluster.

If the cluster mean values are [3.5, 5.0, 2.5], and the threshold is 0.1 , then the limits for each dimension of that cluster would be [3.15 to 3.85, 4.5 to 5.5, 2.25 to 2.75].

What clustering algorithm would be best to achieve this, calculating the number of clusters automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical clustering are generally very easy to implement and produce quite good results.
You have two ways: agglomerative and divise, tho the majority of researches use agglomerative.

In the agglomerative version, you start by considering each element a cluster, then you calculate the distance between all elements and join two clusters based on that distance (i.e. if it's less than a threshold)...

The distance between clusters can be the distance between their means, or the max/min distance (read: single-linkage clustering, complete linkage clustering)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a relative threshold, instead of an absolute threshold?

What should happen when objects don't fall into your "clusters"? What *is* a good cluster in the first place? Are clusters allowed to overlap (otherwise: use every object as a cluster!)? What is a *good* overall clustering?

Consider this data set:

```
0     100 101 102     200 202 204
```

What should happen with the zero?

Or this one:

```
-1 0 1     100 101 102     200 202 204
```

What should "threshold" be for the first cluster?

Or this one:

```
0 1 2     100 101 102     200 202 204
```

For the first cluster, the mean is 1, and the threshold required is 1. For the second cluster, the mean is 101, and using the same threshold of 1 means it includes 0 and 202. (but not 204).

Comment: All values will be greater than zero. The threshold is a proportion instead of the same value for all clusters. If 1 is the mean and threshold is 0.1, limits are 0.9 to 1.1 . if values don't fall in clusters, they become a new cluster. A good cluster is the group of values at a short distance of the mean, the limit is given by the threshold which is a proportion of the mean. Not sure if they would overlap, don't know how to handle that.

Comment: They will overlap. Assuming your threshold is 0.1, and cluster 1 is at 1 (i.e. 0.9-1.1) a value at 1.11 would become a new cluster, and overlap almost half with this first cluster...
Relative overlap should be absolute overlap in logspace. So why not log-transform your data and use something simpler?

Comment: It's interesting the log scale to use a fixed threshold, although the limits will be relatively the same in both scales so the overlap will persist. Perhaps those elements that don't get in any cluster could get discarded, taken as noise. My doubt is the steps needed to build the clusters, how the mean value is going to be computed, and getting those elements that belong to more than one cluster in the "right one".

Comment: You'll have to define "quality", for your application. As is, there are still plenty of admissible "clusterings" (I don't think, "clustering" is the right term either - maybe "vector quantization"?).